# synology: rsync via ssh requires full path

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, path, synology

I found the following behaviour on a Synology RS814+

```
> ssh backup01 rsync
Permission denied, please try again.

> ssh backup01 'which rsync'
/usr/bin/rsync

> ssh backup01 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

> ssh backup01 '/usr/bin/rsync'
[... rsync version and usage information ...]
```

Who can explain why the first and the last command don't do the same thing?

Comment: The last one works or it only shows info?

Comment: It only shows info, but that's what I expect it to do when I call it without arguments, so for the purpose of this demonstration it works.

Comment: My bad, the correct question should be: Can you rsync any file/folder using '/usr/bin/rsync'? Maybe rsync only runs on synology with some privileges.

Comment: No, the question is why the first and the last command don't do the same, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: meybe there is a alias for rsync ?

Comment: That what I thought too, but 'which rsync' should show that.

Comment: No, `which` doesn't show aliases (on all shells). Try `type rsync`. That usually is a shell built-in.

Comment: A quick experiment shows `which` shows aliases in zsh, but not in bash.

Comment: @ams: Good to know! However, `type` gave the same result here.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters between `` runs locally.

If you login through ssh to RS814+ it says: 
`which rsync` >> `/usr/syno/bin/rsync`.

Rsync is intended for host to host transfer, and your system is asking his rsync location (alias) to Synology's one.

The correct way is:

`ssh backup01 /usr/syno/bin/rsync`